# Deriving elegant or 'nice' axis values on graphs using Excel - lookup function or formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to automatically calculate the most elegant y-axis scale (maximum, and division value) for some bar charts. I'm using Excel integrated with a dashboard tool (SAP Dashboards) to display two charts side by side for easy comparison. I need these charts to have identical y-axis scales so they can be compared easily.

Here is a picture to explain what I mean: two charts showing different data, but scaled identically to aid comparison:

[image]

Clearly, the y-axis must be scaled to accommodate the biggest value, whether it's on the left or right. In this case, the biggest value is on the left graph. I used an excel MAX function to find the biggest value (4,668), and then I applied some logic to a) derive an elegant upper bound (4,700) and division value (1,200). I used the LEN function to evaluate how many digits the number has, and the CEILING function to round it up to the nearest 'nice' whole number.

Luckily my dashboard package allows me to customise the y-axis min and max values, as well as the division. I can set these by pointing to a cell.

My question, then, is how to scale this 'logic' to produce elegant max and division values for any dataset, whether the numbers are low or high. Excel does the same thing when it auto scales your axes. I need to replicate that so I can do it programatically in Excel.

For values 0 to 10, the max y axis can be the value itself.

```
11 - 15: I'd set the max to 15, which looks elegant.
16 - 20: 20
21 - 25: 25
etc (going up in 5s)
101 - 110: 110
111 - 120: 120
etc...
1001 - 1100: 1100
```

As you can see, as the values in my data (which can vary widely) increase, I need to elegantly select an upper y value that will look good on my chart. What's the best way to do this?

I also haven't figured out the nicest way to choose 4 or 5 division values that must be 'nice' numbers (eg multiples of 2, or 5, or 10, or 20, or indeed 2000).

My formula must scale nicely, in much the same way that Excel's auto scale produces great results no matter what the order of magnitude of the input data. Can anyone suggest how best to accomplish this?

Comment: This is something I've wanted to get to the bottom of for a while! Not quite got something of sufficient quality for a formal answer yet, but this may be enough for you to use. I offer this without the normal walkthrough explanation I'd include for an answer, hope you can make sense of it! In short it looks for the most appropriate multiple of 10/5/2 to use. Download to Excel, I don't think Google sheets can handle it. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_AO4UFiykURFozRlJLQ2h5NXM Hope to come back to this at some point to post an answer properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought, I believe I have devised a solution to my axis scaling problem. There are many similar posts on other sites, but often their number scaling was quite 'jumpy'. My solution is fully customisable, and I encourage anyone to use it and adapt it to suit their needs.

The solution can be explored in an excel workbook available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sharingaz191/Axes%20Scaling%20Final.xlsx?attredirects=0&d=1)

The process is driven by a simple lookup table that divides all values between 1 and 10 into pleasant 'chunks'. I have used multiples of 4, 5, 6 and 7, although I note that Excel uses multiples of 9 too. Here is the lookup table:

```
  MaxValues   Ticks   Step  
 ----------- ------- ------ 
  10          5       2     
  8           4       2     
  7           7       1     
  6           6       1     
  5           5       1     
  4           4       1     
  3.5         7       0.5   
  3           6       0.5   
  2.5         5       0.5   
  2           4       0.5   
  1.8         6       0.3   
  1.5         5       0.3   
  1.4         7       0.2   
  1.2         6       0.2   
  1           4       0.25
```

For any value, find the closest 'maxvalue', and this will tell you the max value to plot on your axis, along with the number of ticks, and the tick size. So, for example, if the biggest value in your data is 7.5, my system would return 8 as the max value for the graph, split into four ticks of 2.

It can of course handle values smaller than 1 and bigger than 10, using some *log* and *pow* functions. Test it for yourself: open up the [spreadsheet](https://sites.google.com/site/sharingaz191/Axes%20Scaling%20Final.xlsx?attredirects=0&d=1), put a new value in the yellow input box, and see how the values update.

You can customise the list of breakpoints to suit your needs. I have included all the formulae in the spreadsheet along with some descriptions to help.